# SOA Solution Design and Service Encapsulation: Should I keep service codebases in separate solutions, or all together in one?

Tags: nservicebus, soa

I am developing an SOA project using principles I learned in Udi Dahan's Advanced Distributed Systems Design course. So far the project has 6 completely independent services, as well as an IT/Ops service for aggregation and integration with third party services. I also have a set of libraries I've developed for use across all of these services with infrastructure code, i/o, and utilities.

Is it better to keep these services' code together under one solution, or to keep them in entirely separate solutions? Or both? Integration testing will be much simpler with one solution, but I'm concerned with service encapsulation - my gut tells me I don't want a developer working on one service to know how another service works, because it can lead to unintentional coupling. Has anyone run into real-world issues with service encapsulation when keeping all codebases under one solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would keep the services in separate solutions or even separate repositories.

I don't think it has anything to do with service encapsulation, but more to help deal with code contention better and make it hard to take dependancies between services.

As for common code (like contracts) put them in a separate repository and use nuget (or similar) to reference form your solutions.

Make sense?